# Index-based addition with multiplicity in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array

`nparr = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])`

The output of the operation `nparr[[1,3,3,4]] += 1` on this array is:

`array([10, 21, 30, 41, 51])`

Even though the index '3' appears twice. Is there any operation that would let me add with multiplicity, so that the result becomes `array([10, 21, 30, 42, 51])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the np.add.at method to add elements to a NumPy array with multiplicity.

```
import numpy as np

# Create a NumPy array
nparr = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

# Use np.add.at to add elements to the array with multiplicity
np.add.at(nparr, [1, 3, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1])

# Print the updated array
print(nparr)
```

In this code, the `np.add.at` method is used to add 1 to the elements at indices 1, 3, and 4 in the array nparr, and to add 2 to the element at index 3 in the array (since the index appears twice in the list of indices). The output of this code is:

```
array([10, 21, 30, 42, 51])
```

As you can see, the values were added to the array with multiplicity, so that the element at index 3 was incremented by 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Nice. And, I just tested, `np.add.at(nparr, [1, 3, 3, 4], 1)` also works, broadcasting the `1` as one would expect.

Comment: @Hugo did you use chatGPT to provide this answer? This is forbidden by the rules